# Hide .php extension from window server hosting

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to hide the .php extension from Windows-based hosting.

I am trying this using web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule> 
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It shows a 404 error, Please suggest where is the problem.

Comment: This rule working fine for my environment. I think its not related with your rewrite rule. Did you checked event logs ? How your php handler works for iis, it should be fast-cgi ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing PHP on Windows IIS environment also and your rule works pretty fine for my environment. Check my web.config which works perfectly for me maybe this helps you;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization fileEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                   <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PHP" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\php\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

PS: If this won't works for you you may check `Event Viewer` for your Windows OS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i run your given code i find the error "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error"

Comment: Is your server a shared host ? Can you check this link for result code: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055

Comment: and i think it is IIS 8.0